# Java Swing Button: setColor doesn't display the right color

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button

In this program I've got a problem because the color of the button isn't the same I set.

```
...

jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
jButton1.setBackground(new Color(103,175,63));
jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Futura", 1, 14));
jButton1.setForeground(Color.white);
jButton1.setText("Potvrdit");

...
```

(These are the only lines that somehow set the button)

button image:
[image: button image]

how I want the button to be:
[image: how I want the button to be]

button without border:
[image: button without border]

Comment: what color do you want? Can you add an image of how you want the button to be?

Comment: I just want fully green background and white foreground but for some weird reason, even tough I set it, doesn't happen. The image is added.

Comment: Remove the 8px border...

Comment: That's not the point of my problem. My problem is that the color which appears isn't the real color I'm setting in the parameters...

Comment: It's long winded, but [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984558/how-to-change-background-color-of-a-jbutton-from-a-derived-class-in-java-swing/32985267#32985267) demonstrates the basic concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 b1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
 b1.setBackground(new Color(103,175,63));
 b1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Futura", 1, 14));
 b1.setForeground(Color.white);
 b1.setText("Potvrdit");
 b1.setOpaque(true);
 b1.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(103,175,63), 1, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the true background color, in addition the `setBackground()` try to use:

`jButton1.setOpaque(true);`

Also, to remove that gray border, you can use:

`jButton1.setBorderPainted(false);`

Comment: It may also be required to use `setContentAreaFilled`